# Java threads are not working in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Below is my code. I am expecting t1 and t2 should run in parallel but after completion of t1 , t2 is beginning. Am I doing anything wrong . Actually I am trying to replicate producer and consumer problem but some where I am making some mess.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BankThread {

    static List<String> amount = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deposit dep = new Deposit();
        WithDraw wDraw = new WithDraw();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(dep);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(wDraw);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }

}

class Deposit extends BankThread implements Runnable {

    public void run(){
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            amount.add(""+(i*100));
            System.out.println("Deposit #" + i
            + " put: " + i);
            try {
            Thread.sleep((int)(1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }

    }
}

class WithDraw extends BankThread implements Runnable{

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("In withdraw"+amount.size());
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i< amount.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Withdraw #" + amount.get(i)
                    + " removed " + amount.remove(i));
            Thread.sleep((int)(1000));
            }} catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please go through Jenkov tutorial on multi threading        http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html

Comment: @somashaker, http://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/multithreading-in-java/

Comment: Thanks Gladiator and sharathkumar

Comment: Can you please propose more descriptive title for this question?

Answer (score 1):

When I ran it, the output was:

```
Deposit #1 put: 1
In withdraw1
Withdraw #100 removed 100
Deposit #2 put: 2
Deposit #3 put: 3
Deposit #4 put: 4
Deposit #5 put: 5
Deposit #6 put: 6
Deposit #7 put: 7
Deposit #8 put: 8
Deposit #9 put: 9
```

So they did run in parallel. The problem is that withdraw only went through the loop once which is probably not what I wanted.

The reason is it looks at the size of amount once at the beginning of the for loop so it doesn't see the new items.